# ggplot2 - Percent outcome with comma instead of dot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with ggplot2, i try to get a percent-outcome with comma instead of dot in my barplot, because I am from Germany and we use dot and comma opposite. This outcome should be shown in the bars.

I'll show you the whole programming I got 'til now

```
    ggplot(dataframe[!is.na(dataframe$variable), ], aes(x=variable,  group=1)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
    geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
               y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count")
```

I also found the option format(x, decimal.mark=","), but this fits only for axis labeling.

It would be fantastic if you could help me :)

Comment: Could you provide data, because there may be a way to label your barplot, but that method may need some preprocessing?

Comment: How about `label = gsub("\\.",",",scales::percent(..prop..))`?

Comment: @MikeH. Thank you very much :) it fits